# What's the other common expression for "You get what you pay for" in reference to high quality?

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

I’m looking for a familiar saying that I can use for *If you pay more money, you get more quality*.

Because Google has been giving me the same result — that the meaning of the saying *You get what you pay for* is that if you pay less money, and that stuff got broken too soon, then you deserved it. The cheaper, the poorer in quality.

Comment: It’s used for both. Because it’s the same principle.

Comment: Alright. Thanks! Why not post it as answer?

Comment: Because this is a simple matter of googling "You get what you pay for". ELU tries to maintain standards, and this includes closing questions where reasonable research has not been shown to be done, especially where a sensible search would readily provide the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't exert in posting this question if I could find what I was looking for. I mentioned `Because Google has been giving me the same result`.

Comment: Like, "Why settle for less"?

Comment: There are definitions that say the phrase can be used for any price range, but it's rare for someone to buy something like a nice sports car which runs well, and someone says, "yeah you get what you pay for". The phrase is generally used for cheap stuff

Comment: Thanks @user47014. I have the same thing in mind. It's usually used for blaming a person for buying a cheap stuff. :)

Comment: To me, simply reversing the order conveys the "high quality" message. You pay for what you get.

Comment: I've always used *you get what you pay for* to refer to high-quality items too. The particular quality makes no difference to the phrase itself.